# NEST ElasticSearch Cache QueryDescriptor for future use

Tags: c#, caching, elasticsearch, nest

We have a search engine with paging where we can free text search.

We are building up a query like this:

```
var skip = 0;
var take = 20;

var query = Query<Foo>.Bool(bq => bq.Must(m => m.Term("mandatoryField", mandatoryValue)));

var otherQuery = Query<Foo>.Bool(bq => bq.Must(m => m.QueryString(qs => qs.Query("some text")))));

query &= otherQuery;

var response = Client.Search<Foo>(s => s
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take)
    .Sort(// sort on field)
    .Query(q => q.MatchAll() && query);

CacheQuery(query) // here the query contains a bool query descriptor;
```

This query needs to be reused when going to another page. Say:

```
var skip = 20;
var take = 20;

var query = GetCache(); // When retrieving the cache from redis, all the information is lost.
var response = Client.Search<Foo>(s => s
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take)
    .Sort(// sort)
    .Query(q => q.MatchAll() && query);
```

However, when trying to cache the query (using redis), the information from the query is lost.

I've tried to deserialize the query by: query.GetCustomJson(); but still the information is lost.

The question here is; in which manner should I cache the query?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not caching it at all. You say it's a search engine with paging. What happens when you browse to page 3 and close the browser for the day and open it again the next day? You should provide real urls to each page so that users can share search results etc. Pick up the arguments from the url and build the query on each request instead of caching.